# Is this bunk bed design feasible?

Tags: joinery, furniture, design

This is my first plan and it is supposed to be a bunk bed for two kids. The lower mattress (120 x 160cm) is at the floor level. The frame material is 70x70mm pine. The tall pillars extend till the ceiling and there will be a cargo net like safety net.

Am I missing something crucial and any recommendations for the joints? Most of the joints should be possible to take apart.

[image: bunk bed with mattresses]
[image: Updated joints]

Edit: I updated the close up. I would secure these with long screws. The bottoms of the pillars are still a bit of a head ache.

Comment: Will this be freestanding or will it anchor to a wall(s). OR  will the posts anchor to structural members above?

Comment: 2 ideas: allow airspace underneath for ventilation/drying. And the upper platform could be stronger if the joints don't butt into the uprights. (In other words, make a complete independent platform, and bolt/bracket the upright to that platform.)

Comment: Freestanding. But the plan B is to bolt it to the wall.

Comment: This could be made to work for a shelf with static loads, but I wouldn't trust it with a person climbing on top and shifting around on a mattress. I presume you are inquiring about the physical durability and strength of your design, so I am marking this as a duplicate of another question whose answers cover joining methods used in beds. If you intended something different, please feel free to edit and/or open a question on meta.

Comment: Another item worth noting; you did not mention the mass of the person who will occupy the top bunk. This will be an important consideration, and you will need to multiply the child's weight by some factor to get a more realistic load figure, especially if that child likes to jump on the bed once in a while...that's why the top has a tall net and the bottom bunk is as low as possible, right? ;)